# Write a dictionary with multiple values to store data in columns in the CSV file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am trying to write following dictionary into csv file:

```
mydict = {'k1':[1,2,3], 'k2':[4,5,6], 'k3':[6,7,8]}
```

The result I want to achieve is to have dictionary keys as column headers is csv file and map corresponding key values to those columns:

```
k1 k2 k3
1 4 6
2 5 7
3 6 8
```

I have tried following code but it's not working for me:

```
import csv

def save_output(output_file_name):
    global output
    fields = list(mydict.keys())
    with open(output_file_name, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(mydict.items())
        for key,items in mydict.items():
            for item in items:
                writer.writerow(key,item)

save_output('test_output.csv')
```

Comment: Hi! What's not working? - error, unexpected output, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've modified your function so it doesn't use a global variable which generally should be avoid whenever possible. The "trick" here is to use the built-in [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function to transpose the values in the dictionary so they're in column-major instead of row-major order.

To understand better what's going on in the code below, first consider that the `dictionary.values()` call is producing the following sequence from the sample data shown in the dictionary in your question:

```
[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [6, 7, 8]
```

All of these are passed to the `zip()` function all-at-once by using the following shorthand Python notation (note the `*` prefix):

```
zip(*dictionary.values())
```

Which is equivalent to calling it like this:

```
zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [6, 7, 8])
```

So the `zip()` function rearranges them resulting it it producing this sequence:

```
(1, 4, 6), (2, 5, 7), (3, 6, 8)
```

Another way to to think about is to consider the values as a 2D matrix:

```
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
6, 7, 8
```

in which case `zip()` is doing to them:

```
1, 4, 6
2, 5, 7
3, 6, 8
```

In other words, it's exchanging the rows and columns of the matrix, which is called "transposing" the matrix. As I said, it's being done here to put them into the order needed to write the column values row-by-row into csv file.

Anyway, here's the code:

```
import csv

def save_output(dictionary, output_file_name):
    with open(output_file_name, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(dictionary)  # First row (the keys of the dictionary).
        for values in zip(*dictionary.values()):
            writer.writerow(values)

mydict = {'k1': [1, 2, 3], 'k2': [4, 5, 6], 'k3': [6, 7, 8]}

save_output(mydict, 'test_output.csv')
```

Contents of the `test_output.csv` file produced:

```
k1,k2,k3
1,4,6
2,5,7
3,6,8
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin, this worked for me this time :)
Would you be able to explain in more detail how the following code works as I am bit confused:

for values in zip(*dictionary.values()):
            writer.writerow(values)

Answer (score 3):

If you're not opposed to `pandas`, this is very easy:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(mydict).to_csv('filename.csv',index=None, sep=' ')
```

Note, the `sep=' '` is to have it as a space delimited csv. You can omit that (or use `sep=','`, which is the default) to have it as a regular comma separated csv

Comment: Thanks @sacul, was going to give it try but for some reason I can't import panda module.

Comment: You might have to install it (but note that it is `pandas`, not `panda`)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
import csv

def save_output(mydict, output_file_name):
    keys = [list(mydict.keys())]
    values = [mydict[key] for key in mydict.keys()]
    final = keys + values
    with open(output_file_name, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
        writer.writerows(final)

mydict = {'k1':[1,2,3], 'k2':[4,5,6], 'k3':[6,7,8]}

save_output(mydict, "output_file_name.csv")
```

The output when you open the `csv` file is this:

```
k1 k2 k3
1 2 3
4 5 6
6 7 8
```

Comment: The data is not in the desired order in the output csv file produced.